# Ideas for creating a "Did you mean XYZ" feature into website

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'd like to give users the ability to search through a large list of businesses, but still find near matches.

Does anyone have any recommendations on how best to go about this when you're not targeting simple dictionary words, but instead complex names like ABC Business Name?

Regards.

Comment: I agree.  I admire the depth of knowledge of my fellow software engineers and all of these answers are good leads.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the wikipedia article on [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).  It's a fairly simple concept to wrap your head around and pretty easy to implement an algorithm in whichever language you are using, in your case, C#.

I found an example in C# for you [here](http://www.merriampark.com/ldcsharp.htm).

Also, [here](http://www.norvig.com/spell-correct.html) is an example of a spelling corrector from Peter Norvig of Google.  It was said on the SO podcast a few episodes ago that Jon Skeet attempted a rewrite of this same algorithm in C#.  Not sure if he completed it and/or made it publicly available though.

Comment: Great stuff.  I'm going to adapt this to operate SQL server-side as a sproc to get the best possible performance and only use it when there are no matches.  Thanks for the insight.

Comment: As an update, this has been implemented in C# here http://www.codegrunt.co.uk/2010/11/02/C-Sharp-Norvig-Spelling-Corrector.html

Answer (score 2):

Consider using Keyword match and edit distance based similarity.  Might combine with 'original searched' to 'actually clicked'.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a crazy solution but could you split the business name by space and then search either all the items or maybe the first couple.

So you might search on 'ABC' and 'Business' but leave out 'Name' as this might take too long.

You might even check to see if the string is of a certain length, then trim and just search on the first say 5 letters.

Have you had a look at "[soundex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx)" as a way of searching through your businesses.  Again, I think you'd need to split the name by space.

Answer (score 1):

You might check out the SQL Server [SOUNDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384%28SQL.90%29.aspx) and [DIFFERENCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188753%28SQL.90%29.aspx) functions.  SOUNDEX converts a sequence of characters (such as a word) into a 4-character code which will be the same for similar-sounding words.  DIFFERENCE gives a number which represents how "different" two strings are based on sound.

You could, for example, create a computed column based on the SOUNDEX function and match on that column later.  Or you could use DIFFERENCE in a WHERE clause.

Comment: You can also do a google search for MetaPhone, which is basically a more complex version of Soundex.   Soundex was actually created in 1918 and is a very simple/basic algorithm.   Metaphone generally will give better matches, but is not built into SQL, although there are numerous T-SQL versions of it around