# Spell Check Feature in C# Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, forms, spell-checking

I'm working on creating a windows form application with C# and I was wondering how I could implement a type of spell check feature.

To be specific I have several TextBoxes. The user will enter the information into the TextBox. I have set the auto complete on and the source to a database table. If their entry was something that was not in the table I would like to make a suggestion based on a similar entry in the database.

Ex they enter Bobb. I want to pop up with a label next to it saying " did you mean Bob?" if Bob is in my table.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713963/spell-check-in-winforms

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870178/ideas-for-creating-a-did-you-mean-xyz-feature-into-website

Comment: You could try using wpf...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance maybe this could help.

Comment: why use wpf over windows forms?